# How to insert in to two tables from an online from?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to insert in to two tables at once? I need to insert some data in to a table (students) and then based on the primary key insert in to another (enrollments). Is this possible?
The enrollments table however pulls other primary key from another table called schools (id).

```
public function add()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $this->student_validation();
        if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
            $data = $this->_get_posted_student_data();
            $insert_id = $this->student->insert('students', $data);
            if($insert_id) {
                $this->__insert_enrollment($insert_id);
                success($this->lang->line('insert_success'));
                redirect('web/index/' . $data['front_school_id']);
            } else {
                error($this->lang->line('insert_failed'));
                redirect('web/admission');
            }
        } else {
            $this->data['post'] = $_POST;
        }
    }
    $this->data['schools'] = $this->schools;
    $this->data['add'] = TRUE;
    $this->layout->title($this->lang->line('add') . ' ' . $this->lang->line('student') . ' | ' . SMS);
    $this->layout->view('web/index', $this->data);
}

private function __insert_enrollment($insert_id)
{
    $data = array();
    $school = $this->student->get_school_by_id($this->input->post('front_school_id'));
    $data['student_id'] = $insert_id;
    $data['school_id'] = $this->input->post('front_school_id');
    //$data['class_id'] = $this->input->post('class_id');
    //$data['section_id'] = $this->input->post('section_id');
    $data['academic_year_id'] = $school->academic_year_id;
    //$data['roll_no'] = $this->input->post('roll_no');
    $data['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //$data['created_by'] = logged_in_user_id();
    $data['status'] = 1;
    $this->db->insert('enrollments', $data);
}

private function _get_posted_student_data()
{
    $items = array();
    $school_id = $this->session->userdata('front_school_id');
    $items[] = 'first_name';
    $items[] = 'middle_name';
    $items[] = 'last_name';
    $items[] = 'gender';
    $items[] = 'religion';
    $items[] = 'dobpin';
    $items[] = 'address';
    $items[] = 'immunization_update';
    $items[] = 'nationality';
    $items[] = 'valid_permit';
    $items[] = 'relation_father';
    $items[] = 'father_name';
    $items[] = 'father_phone';
    $items[] = 'father_email';
    $items[] = 'father_address';
    $items[] = 'relation_mother';
    $items[] = 'mother_name';
    $items[] = 'mother_phone';
    $items[] = 'mother_email';
    $items[] = 'mother_address';
    $items[] = 'other_sibling';
    $items[] = 'name_sibling';
    $items[] = 'class_sibling';
    $items[] = 'name';
    $items[] = 'relation';
    $items[] = 'child';
    $items[] = 'application_name';
    $data = elements($items, $_POST);
    $data['dob'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('dob')));
    $data['admission_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('admission_date')));
    $data['age'] = floor((time() - strtotime($data['dob'])) / 31556926);
    $data['modified_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //$data['modified_by'] = logged_in_user_id();
    $data['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //$data['created_by'] = logged_in_user_id();
    $data['status'] = 1;
    // create user 
    //$data['user_id'] = $this->student->create_user();
    if($_FILES['birth_certificate']['name']) {
        $data['birth_certificate'] = $this->_upload_birth_certificate();
    }
    if($_FILES['bill']['name']) {
        $data['bill'] = $this->_upload_bill();
    }
    if($_FILES['immunization']['name']) {
        $data['immunization'] = $this->_upload_immunization();
    }
    if($_FILES['photo']['name']) {
        $data['photo'] = $this->_upload_photo();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: For the sake of readability, you should take care of indentation in you code blocks.

Comment: With the indents there, I was nit able to post the question

Comment: "_Is it possible to insert in to two tables at once?_" The answer to your question is "_Yes._"

Answer (score 1):

You need `$this->db->insert_id()` to get last inserted id which will get from this.

```
$this->db->insert('students', $data);
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
if(!empty($insert_id)) {
  $this->__insert_enrollment($insert_id);
  success($this->lang->line('insert_success'));
  redirect('web/index/' . $data['front_school_id']);
} else {
  error($this->lang->line('insert_failed'));
  redirect('web/admission');
}
```

Comment: This still didn't work. Its doing the redirect in the if part (    redirect('web/index/' . $data['front_school_id']);) but just not entering into the database.

Comment: did you debug it? check your `$data` array before insert line, check `$insert_id` before if condition

Comment: I did.. still nothing